# Unexpected biber behavior with latexmk in TeXstudio

Tags: biblatex, biber, latexmk

I am using TeXstudio with `latexmk` as my default compiler with the following modification to the command:-
`latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape" %` (for `svg` package).

Here is my MWE:-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=count]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
{\iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
    \bibopenbracket}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\supercitedelim}
{\bibclosebracket}
\let\cite=\supercite
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
This book\supercite{ElvangBook}.
\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `references.bib`:-

```
@book{ElvangBook,
    author = "Elvang, Henriette and Huang, Yu-tin",
    title = "{Scattering Amplitudes in Gauge Theory and Gravity}",
    isbn = "978-1-316-19142-2, 978-1-107-06925-1",
    publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
    month = "4",
    year = "2015"
}
```

The issue is that whenever I make changes to my .bib file and save changes and run `latexmk`, biber breaks and I lose my citations. To fix the issue, I have to comment out \addbibresource{references.bib}, run `latexmk` and then uncomment it and then run `latexmk` again to fix the citations.

Is this intended behaviour? What can be done to make this workflow easier? I would like to dynamically make changes to my references, so it is not feasible for me to do the citations at the end.

Thanks.

Comment: The example has `\supercite{Elvang}` in the `.tex` file but `@book{ElvangBook,` in the `.bib` file. If I change both to the same entry key (`ElvangBook`), I get absolutely no problem running this example with `latexmk`. Changes in the `.bib` file are picked up and Biber is run correctly. Can you explain in more detail how Biber "breaks"? Are there errors or warnings? Is there any log message that would help us here?

Comment: That was a typo. I fixed it now. Let me share the log message too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to add the log file as moewe suggested, I noticed that the error said to run biber. But I assumed that it was being chosen automatically by `latexmk` but that wasn't the case. My TeXstudio settings had the default bibliography tool chosen as BibTeX and upon changing it to Biber, my problem resolved itself.

This was a silly mistake, and I am leaving this for future users who might face the same.

Thanks.

Comment: That does not make much sense, if your texstudio runs latexmk (which it does not by default) it will pick up the need for biber automatically regardless of the texstudio settings (I've never seen otherwise), but if you use the build in compiling tool (which is not latexmk) then that will use the bib tool registered in the texstudio settings.

Comment: `latexmk` is usually extremely good at running Biber correctly. It would really surprise me if it got things wrong here. But the default build tool of TeXmaker does not use `latexmk` it uses its own heuristic (that is in my experience inferior to `latexmk`). If you want to use `latexmk` in TeXmaker, you need to explicitly set that up.

Comment: I see @daleif. I expected similar behaviour from latexmk. Here are screenshots of my texstudio configuration (only the default bibliography tool has been modified to biber, before that it was biblatex by default) https://imgur.com/a/MFVIL1z

Comment: @moewe, have a look at the above comment. Let me know if I have to change something

Comment: Hmmm. If `latexmk` was indeed the default compile invocation it should have worked. The only other explanation I have is that for some reason the "Recompile Bibliography" function was used. It is defined as `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile`, which is overkill if `txs:///compile` is `latexmk`, because `latexmk` will run the bibliography tool when required and could be harmful if `txs:///bibliography` is set to BibTeX, because that would mean TeXstudio forcibly runs BibTeX when Biber needs to be run and is run by `latexmk`.

Comment: If `txs:///compile` is set to run LaTeXmk, it should be enough to set "Recompile Bibliography" also to just `txs:///compile`.

Comment: @moewe I made the change you suggested and it does indeed work fine. "Recompile Bibliography" was actually being used, so I think your guess was correct.